# Hibernate Configuration initialization : java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, classcastexception, jboss-logging

I am trying to write data in a MariaDB database.

I have a ClassCastException calling `new Configuration().configure()`.
It seems to be related to jboss logging utility.

Did you already run into this case?

I use hibernate-core 5.3.7.Final, here is my "src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml" file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- database connection properties -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/pdfconsolidation?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- show mysql queries output in console -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- manage automatic database creation -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- add resources here -->
        <mapping class="com.navblue.joget.pdfconsolidation.bean.Page"/>
        <mapping class="com.navblue.joget.pdfconsolidation.bean.Manual"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is my stack trace :

```
ERROR 14 nov. 2018 10:13:26 org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.error500_jsp  - org.apache.jasper.el.JspELException: /WEB-INF/jsp/ubuilder/v5view.jsp(11,4) '${processer.html}' Error reading [html] on type [org.joget.apps.userview.service.UserviewThemeProcesser]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.el.JspELException: /WEB-INF/jsp/ubuilder/v5view.jsp(11,4) '${processer.html}' Error reading [html] on type [org.joget.apps.userview.service.UserviewThemeProcesser]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:565)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.joget.commons.util.AnalyzerFilter.doFilter_aroundBody0(AnalyzerFilter.java:17)
    at org.joget.commons.util.AnalyzerFilter.doFilter_aroundBody1$advice(AnalyzerFilter.java:54)
    at org.joget.commons.util.AnalyzerFilter.doFilter(AnalyzerFilter.java:1)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.joget.apps.workflow.security.WorkflowHttpAuthProcessingFilter.doFilter(WorkflowHttpAuthProcessingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.joget.commons.spring.web.CustomDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(CustomDelegatingFilterProxy.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.joget.apps.app.web.ExpireFilter.doFilter(ExpireFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.el.JspELException: /WEB-INF/jsp/ubuilder/v5view.jsp(11,4) '${processer.html}' Error reading [html] on type [org.joget.apps.userview.service.UserviewThemeProcesser]
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:123)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.ubuilder.v5view_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f0(v5view_jsp.java:250)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.ubuilder.v5view_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(v5view_jsp.java:207)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.ubuilder.v5view_jsp._jspService(v5view_jsp.java:158)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.navblue.joget.pdfconsolidation.dao.HibernateDAO.getSessionFactory(HibernateDAO.java:24)
    at com.navblue.joget.pdfconsolidation.dao.HibernateDAO.openCurrentSessionWithTransaction(HibernateDAO.java:36)
    at com.navblue.joget.pdfconsolidation.PageIndexFileUploader.execute(PageIndexFileUploader.java:84)
    at org.joget.apps.app.service.AppWorkflowHelper.executeTool(AppWorkflowHelper.java:125)
    at org.joget.workflow.shark.WorkflowToolActivityHandler.executeActivity(WorkflowToolActivityHandler.java:69)
    at org.enhydra.shark.WfActivityImpl.runTool(WfActivityImpl.java:1487)
    at org.enhydra.shark.WfActivityImpl.startActivity(WfActivityImpl.java:1419)
    at org.enhydra.shark.WfActivityImpl.activate(WfActivityImpl.java:261)
    at org.enhydra.shark.WfProcessImpl.startActivity(WfProcessImpl.java:918)
    at org.enhydra.shark.WfProcessImpl.queueNext(WfProcessImpl.java:1134)
    at org.enhydra.shark.WfProcessImpl.run(WfProcessImpl.java:750)
    at org.enhydra.shark.WfProcessImpl.activity_complete(WfProcessImpl.java:969)
    at org.enhydra.shark.WfActivityImpl.finish(WfActivityImpl.java:441)
    at org.enhydra.shark.WfActivityImpl.complete(WfActivityImpl.java:366)
    at org.enhydra.shark.WfActivityWrapper.complete(WfActivityWrapper.java:230)
    at org.joget.workflow.model.service.WorkflowManagerImpl.assignmentComplete(WorkflowManagerImpl.java:4241)
    at org.joget.workflow.model.service.WorkflowManagerImpl.assignmentComplete(WorkflowManagerImpl.java:4264)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.joget.apps.app.service.AuditTrailInterceptor.invoke(AuditTrailInterceptor.java:17)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.joget.apps.app.service.SqlFilterAspect.invoke(SqlFilterAspect.java:36)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.assignmentComplete(Unknown Source)
    at org.joget.apps.app.service.AppServiceImpl.completeAssignmentForm(AppServiceImpl.java:403)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.completeAssignmentForm(Unknown Source)
    at org.joget.apps.userview.lib.RunProcess.assignmentSubmit_aroundBody28(RunProcess.java:476)
    at org.joget.apps.userview.lib.RunProcess.assignmentSubmit_aroundBody29$advice(RunProcess.java:95)
    at org.joget.apps.userview.lib.RunProcess.assignmentSubmit(RunProcess.java:1)
    at org.joget.apps.userview.lib.RunProcess.getJspPage_aroundBody20(RunProcess.java:216)
    at org.joget.apps.userview.lib.RunProcess.getJspPage_aroundBody21$advice(RunProcess.java:95)
    at org.joget.apps.userview.lib.RunProcess.getJspPage(RunProcess.java:1)
    at org.joget.apps.userview.model.UserviewMenu.getReadyJspPage_aroundBody12(UserviewMenu.java:132)
    at org.joget.apps.userview.model.UserviewMenu.getReadyJspPage_aroundBody13$advice(UserviewMenu.java:95)
    at org.joget.apps.userview.model.UserviewMenu.getReadyJspPage(UserviewMenu.java:1)
    at org.joget.apps.userview.service.UserviewUtil.getUserviewMenuHtml(UserviewUtil.java:94)
    at org.joget.apps.userview.service.UserviewThemeProcesser.getContent(UserviewThemeProcesser.java:593)
    at org.joget.apps.userview.service.UserviewThemeProcesser.getHtml(UserviewThemeProcesser.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor255.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:94)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:115)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.navblue.joget.pdfconsolidation.dao.HibernateDAO.getSessionFactory(HibernateDAO.java:22)
    ... 168 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:85)
    ... 169 more
```

If you want more precisions, I'll give them.

Comment: What container are you running in? It looks like there is a jboss-logging mismatch.

Comment: I am developing a plugin for Joget (a COTS). My plugin works outside of Joget, but integrating it I get this error. There seems to be a conflict somewhere. I ended up using this solution, even if it does not do exactly what I want :
https://dev.joget.org/community/display/KBv6/Using+Hibernate+Entity+and+Dao+in+Plugin

Comment: I'm not sure how that worked because the issue is there is a logging version mismatch :)

Comment: I think it works now because I use Joget configuration. There should have been a conflict... I think I have a lot more to learn concerning Java, hibernate and Maven. Thank you for your support. Do you know how I can close this topic?